# PHP session vars are lost after Facebook Connect on IE

Tags: php, facebook, internet-explorer, session, cookies

We are getting very strange behavior of the **$_SESSION** object on **IE11** with **FB Connect**, even when **all type of cookies are enabled** (including 3rd party cookies).

Here's the pseudo flow:

1. User opens the sign-in page.
2. Clicks on FB Connect link which redirects to FB for authentication.
3. OAuth 2.0 flow goes here
4. When everything is o.k, we store user's details in the $_SESSION and loading the secure page.
5. Then, when the user clicks on any link to internal secure page (which simple tests the $_SESSION variable to validate that user details exists), seems like the $_SESSION variable gets empty so the user is automatically signed-out.

   - This happens only on IE (tested on Chrome, FF, Safari & Opera).
   - We've tried to add different P3P headers like suggested [here](http://genotrance.wordpress.com/2006/11/23/session-cookies-rejected-by-internet-explorer/) but it didn't help (we believe the problem is something else).

Please help!

Comment: So your start page, where you initiate the session, is not “secure”? (I assume “secure” means HTTPS here?)

Comment: When I say secure I mean protected behind user/pass combination (not HTTPS).

Comment: OK. So what have you found out in your debug efforts so far? Especially session cookie value before/after each step would be of interest here.

Comment: The PHPSESSID cookie's value remains always the same ('9fnn9ruddtet1hjjcd868uspi7').